# web.config MVC запись

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadLogFile(HttpPostedFileBase download)
    {

        if (download != null){               
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(download.FileName);
            var fullName = Server.MapPath("~/Logs/" + fileName);
            download.SaveAs(fullName);
            //mark a current log-file to process
            **WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFileName"] = fullName;**

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Я хочу перезаписать данные в файл web.config из секции . Не мог найти, как это сделать, может плохо искал. Спасибо

Comment: [раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260317/change-a-web-config-programmatically-with-c-sharp-net), [два](https://www.itprotoday.com/web-application-management/programming-webconfig-file-using-c)?

Answer (score 1):

Сделать надо так:

```
//mark a current log-file to process
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
config.AppSettings.Settings["logFileName"].Value = fullName;
config.Save();
```